# Timeout while trying to query a SNMP server

Tags: linux-networking, snmp, opensuse, snmpd

I am trying to perform a query to a snmp server but I always obtain a timeout error. I am working with SLES 11 (OpenSUSE) and **the firewall is disabled**.

The query I am executin is:

```
> snmpwalk -mALL -v1 -ccomname localhost system 2 > /dev/null
Timeout: No Response from localhost
```

I have tried to allow the access to/from snmp by configuring the files `hosts.allow` and `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`. These files are below:

## hosts.allow

```
snmpd : ALL : ALLOW
```

## snmpd.conf

```
syslocation Server Room
syscontact Sysadmin (root@localhost)

# These really aren't meant for production use.  They include all MIBS
# and can use considerable resources.  See snmpd.conf(5) for information
# on setting up groups and limiting MIBS.
rocommunity public 127.0.0.1
# rwcommunity mysecret 127.0.0.1
```

## netstat

In addition, I have test that the server is actually listening with `netstat`:

```
> sudo netstat -tualpn | grep snmp
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:199           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20561/snmpd         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:161             0.0.0.0:*                           20561/snmpd
```

## log file

In addition, I have inspected the log file:

```
NET-SNMP version 5.4.2.1
Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:47705->[127.0.0.1]
Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:47705->[127.0.0.1]
[...]
Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:39362->[127.0.0.1]
Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:39362->[127.0.0.1]
Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:39362->[127.0.0.1]
Connection from UDP: [127.0.0.1]:39362->[127.0.0.1]
```

I have observed that every time I execute the `snmpwalk` sentence, 6 entries similar to the above are added to the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the community name was wrong, it should be `public` instead of `comname`.

I run the snmp configuration to set the community name as `comname`, but it is still 'public'. I do not know why.